# Any way to set a ResourceDictionary key to match the class name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I've got quite a few `<conv:[ConverterName] x:Key="[ConverterName]"/>` entries in XAML resource dictionaries, and every time the key matches the type name.

Is there any way to have the key take the name from the type automatically, similar to `nameof`? Aside from convenience, I'd like the code to be a bit more refactorproof.

Comment: What is with types with same names, but from different namespaces? ;)

Comment: Yeah, that could be a problem. I always put my converters in a `.Converters` namespace, so I dodge that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in XAML but you can do it programmatically using reflection. Something like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //get all types that implements from all assemlies in the AppDomain
        foreach(var converterType in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
            .Where(t => typeof(IValueConverter).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
                && !t.IsAbstract 
                && !t.IsInterface))
        {
            //...and add them as resources to <Application.Resources>:
            Current.Resources.Add(converterType.Name, Activator.CreateInstance(converterType));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, I get told off for using too much reflection already! I was a little worried this might be the only way, but it makes sense. I'll add a 'and has a default constructor' to the where clause.

Comment: After trying this out, I also added a check for `typeof(IMultiValueConverter).IsAssignableFrom(t)`, to cover (obviously) the multi-value ones as well.